# Join with comma-separated data returned from function using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I am trying hard on this, but I am unable to solve it. I have data coming comma-separated from a column, and I am splitting it with a function, and I need to return all comma-separated values.

I am doing something like **outer join ApplicationDocument Table**.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT PA.Id,
       Ad.Id,
       Ad.DocumentTitle,
       Ad.Path
       ,
       S.value
FROM dbo.ApplicationDocument AS Ad
right JOIN dbo.PostApplication AS PA
ON Ad.ApplicationId = PA.Id
JOIN dbo.Post P
ON PA.JobId = P.Id
outer APPLY dbo.fnSplit(P.RequiredDocuments,',') as S
WHERE S.Value = Ad.DocumentTitle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the follwing query by the help of **@Humpty Dumpty** and **@t-clausen-dk**.

Here is what I needed. This query now fetches all the records, and I can now filter using a `where` clause on it.

```
SELECT PA.Id AS ApplicationId,
       Ad.Id AS ApplicationDocumentId,
       Ad.DocumentTitle,
       Ad.Path,
       S.value
FROM dbo.ApplicationDocument AS Ad
right JOIN dbo.PostApplication AS PA
ON Ad.ApplicationId = PA.Id
JOIN dbo.Post P
ON PA.JobId = P.Id
cross APPLY dbo.fnSplit(P.RequiredDocuments,',') as S

where PA.Id = SomeId here
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CROSS APPlY  (select value 
             from  dbo.fnSplit(P.RequiredDocuments,',')  
             WHERE Value =Ad.DocumentTitle) as  S
```

Comment: it says : the multipart identifier "P.RequiredDocuments" could not be found

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Updated now. You need to use [Cross APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 , almost resolved but need to return all comma seperated values. plz check update

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: You can't return multiple since you have a `where`. so it will return the item only match the condition

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PA.Id, 
       Ad.Id,
       Ad.DocumentTitle,
       Ad.Path,
   X.Value
FROM dbo.ApplicationDocument AS Ad  
JOIN dbo.PostApplication AS PA 
ON Ad.ApplicationId = PA.Id 
JOIN dbo.Post P 
ON PA.JobId = P.Id
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT Value FROM dbo.fnSplit(P.RequiredDocuments,',') as S 
WHERE S.Value = Ad.DocumentTitle) X
```

Comment: 1 up but my issue not resolving. What if i need to return S.Value right outer join with ApplicationDocument. Since the ApplicationDocument may or may not contain that entry

Comment: @EhsanSajjad changed answer to use outer apply. I am assuming you only want matching values.

Answer (score -1):

Check the parenthesis, ')'. It's not properly used:

```
 SELECT PA.Id,Ad.Id,Ad.DocumentTitle,Ad.Path 
 FROM dbo.ApplicationDocument AS Ad  
 INNER JOIN dbo.PostApplication AS PA 
  ON Ad.ApplicationId = PA.Id 
 INNER JOIN dbo.Post P 
  ON PA.JobId = P.Id
 CROSS APPlY  (select value from  dbo.fnSplit(P.RequiredDocuments,',') 
  WHERE Value =Ad.DocumentTitle))
```

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it says : the multipart identifier "P.RequiredDocuments" could not be found

Comment: EhsanSajjad then P.RequiredDocuments might not be there in dbo.Post

Comment: it is there @MadaraUchiha

Comment: Ehsan sajjad use the where condition inside

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: It is not possible. Need `CROSS APPlY` here